# Merge Process In-Place:

Tags: arrays, sorting, merge, mergesort, in-place

Merge Procedure in MergeSort cannot run in-place.
This is my explanation:

Does it add up?

A = 5,1,9,2,10,0

”q”:  pointer to the middle of array at index 2.

We are merging element at q and those to its left with the elements to the right of q.

A= 1,5,10,0,2,12

We point to the beginning of the left side with ”i” and to that of the right with ”j”.

We point to the current position in the array with ”k”.

The algorithm starts with i=0, j=3, k=0.

If we merge in place:for k=0:i= 0, j= 3,0<1  -> A[k] =A[j] andj+ +

> > resulting array:A={0,5,10,0,2,12}

As we can see, we lost the value 1 already.

We will continue to lose values, for example in the next iteration:

for k=1:i= 0, j= 4,0<2  =⇒A[k] =A[i] andi+ +

> > resulting array:A={0,0,10,0,2,12}

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using rotates of sub-arrays. There are in place merge sorts with O(n log(n)) time complexity, but these use a portion of the array as working storage. If stability is needed, then some small subset of unique values (like 2 sqrt(n)) are used to provide the space, since reordering unique values before sorting won't break stability. Getting back to to simple rotate algorithm:

```
 1  5 10  0  2 12
 0  1  5 10  2 12         0 <  1, rotate  0 into place, adjust working indexes
 0  1  5 10  2 12         1 <  2, continue
 0  1  2  5 10 12         2 <  5, rotate  2 into place, adjust working indexes
 0  1  2  5 10 12         5 < 12, continue
 0  1  2  5 10 12        10 < 12, continue, end of left run, done
```